# IF(GROUPING(id)=1, "Total", name) returns the same wrong "name" across all rows, except for the total case

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concatenation

I'm using MySQL 8.0 and performing select query with totals and sub-totals, hence it's about `with rollup` statement.

The problem is that the expression `IF(GROUPING(id)=1, "Total revenue", diagnosis_name)` is returning the same value for `diagnosis_name` in all rows except for those where the grouping id is 1 (i.e., the "Total revenue" rows). Moreover, if I put a fake condition without `GROUPING` (ex. 0=0) the result is correct. Same happens if I take the `diagnosis_name` without the conditional statement at all.

Similar problem happens with `group_concat`, I wonder if the reasons are the same.

**Here is the query result, the `_true` columns shows the correct value**

| id | appointment_id_true | appointment_id | appointment_diagnosis | revenue | appointment_diagnosis_true |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | Туберкулез | 350.00 | Грипп |
| 2 | 12 | 5 | Туберкулез | 0.00 | Туберкулез |
| 2 |  | 1, 12 | Total revenue | 350.00 | Туберкулез |
| 3 | 11 | 5 | Туберкулез | 0.00 | Диарея |
| 3 |  | 11 | Total revenue | 0.00 | Диарея |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | Туберкулез | 120.00 | Наркотическая зависимость |
| 4 |  | 5 | Total revenue | 120.00 | Наркотическая зависимость |
| Total |  | 1, 5, 11, 12 | Total revenue | 470.00 | Наркотическая зависимость |

Not sure if it's good idea to put the SQL query here, so [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kcMvHR2FyKaQvm7QNVnBAt/4)

What is the coveats and how can I make it work in a way sql query describes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42223946/13266817), that when using `GROUP BY` you are only allowed to use either aggregation functions or columns which are specified to be grouped.

I [updated](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kcMvHR2FyKaQvm7QNVnBAt/6) my SQL query so now it uses aggregation functions such as `MAX`, and `CASE` conditions to handle non-grouping values in sub-totals as `NULL`.

Hence, here is the solution:

```sql
@doctor_id_grouping := (GROUPING(doctor_id) = 1),
IF(@doctor_id_grouping, NULL, doctor_name) as doctor_name,
```

```sql
IF(GROUPING(doctor_id), NULL, MAX(doctor_name)) AS doctor_name,
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `WITH`.  Use `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`.  Then test for `NULL` to identify the "Total" row.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you try to achieve, but I would start with:

```
SELECT coalesce(doctor_id, 'Total') as id
     , coalesce(appointment_id, 'Total revenue') as ...
     , sum(amount_charged) AS revenue
FROM ...
```

If you want to aggregate further with group_concat I would do it at an outer level:

```
SELECT ..., GROUP_CONCAT(...)
FROM (
    SELECT coalesce(doctor_id, 'Total') as id
         , coalesce(appointment_id, 'Total revenue') as ...
         , sum(amount_charged) AS revenue
    FROM ...
```

Comment: yeah, I understand that my task can be done using additional select-join queries, but I really try to understand why such doesn't follow the logic: `coalesce(appointment_id, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct appointment_id SEPARATOR ', ')) as appointment_ids`. It just displays the same ids in all rows

Comment: In a sense, you are trying to aggregate and group by at the same time.

Comment: @skill, Updated with an example